# Strage behaviour using Knockout.js 3.2.0, shift is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, knockout.js

This one's been a real hair-puller.
I moved some divs into templates without altering any ko's datacontext, and all of a sudden I had the dreaded "undefined is not a function" in template.

Turns out it wasn't something related to a missing observable, but something internal to ko:

[image: shift is undefined]

Looks like continuousNodeArray is not a plain-old array but it's a jQuery object array (I assume in this particular instance only, as I believe it *should* be a plain-old array).

[image: Array of jQuery objects]

So I'm curious to know if this is a Knockout.js bug or something in my templates triggering this behaviour. I solved this by adding the following:

```
jQuery.fn.shift = [].shift;
```

But I'm sure there must be something else going on. Any clue?

Comment: We really need a repro to be able to answer that question...

Comment: @Jeroen I understand. I'm afraid I can't produce now right now. I'll try and include one when I can (deadline to meet).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is known and not recently (Oct 8) **fixed bug**  when you are using jquery.tmpl as a templating engine.

See on github: [Fix error in fixUpContinuousNodeArray when using jquery.tmpl](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/pull/1513)

So if you check the [latest source](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/blob/a88830e441a34d7ea2c08784ac5dfcc65fe6004d/src/utils.js) you will see now that `splice` is used instead of `shift`:

[image]

However it is not included in the latest version (3.2.0) so you properly should stick to your workaround until a new version comes out.

Comment: Thank you! Kind of relieved it's not strictly an issue with my code .